# On click of button show the value of button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a linkbutton in repeater. i want to get the value of link buton on click.i am using masterpage and id of linkbutton can not determine because it lie in repeater so how to get value from link button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprogress" runat="server" class="label label-info"   BackColor="#589FC2" value='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>' >In progress</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: you can use find control and get the value.then assign it to link button programmatically

Comment: i cannot use find control . i have to do it with javascript only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

code behind

```
    protected void lnkprogress_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int BookingId = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
```

aspx page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprogress" runat="server" class="label label-info"   BackColor="#589FC2" OnCommand="lnkprogress_Command" CommandName="test" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>' >In progress</asp:LinkButton>
```